# Classification Tree in R

Tags: r, tree, classification, rpart, cart-analysis

Am totally new to R and I am trying to make use of classification trees for classifying some data. What has me confused is what library to make use of. Should I make use of rpart or tree?

Comment: Choosing a package is most likely one's choice and this post as such is in one of those "likely to solicit debates" category and is likely to get closed. Please frame your question with less ambiguity. What are you going to do? Have you checked the documentation of both these packages as to what they have to offer..?

Comment: I think this is actually a good question (although the wording could use a little work).  It's very confusing that there are two packages that provide such similar functionality, but actually the rpart package seems to be more widely used and more extensive (but I've never been sure).  I would also encourage researching the party package as well as an extension of rpart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `rpart` package. The `tree` package is included mainly for compatibility with older scripts.